# Drop rows based on values from other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to group a dataframe by **Type** and **Country** and remove those phone numbering `Prefix`es that are longer, if there is a shorter prefix of the same **Type** and **Country**.

e.g. based on the following input:

| Prefix | Type | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | Fixline | Austria |
| 431 | Fixline | Austria |
| 43650 | Mobile | Austria |
| 436501 | Mobile | Austria |
| 43676 | Mobile | Austria |

I would like to have the following output.

| Prefix | Type | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 43 | Fixline | Austria |
| 43650 | Mobile | Austria |
| 43676 | Mobile | Austria |

**431** is dropped, because there is already prefix **43** of the same Type and Country as **431** and **431** starts with **43**.

**436501** is dropped, because there is already prefix **43650** of the same Type and Country as **436501** and **436501** starts with **43650**.

I have not much experience with Pandas.
My first try was this one, but this takes way too long:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in data.iterrows():
        if index2 > index and row['Type'] == row2['Type'] and row['Country'] == row2['Country'] and row['Prefix'].startswith(row2['Prefix']):
            data.drop(index, inplace=True)
            break
```

Comment: Is it as simple as counting the number of digits/length of string in `Prefix`, then keeping the string with minimum-length for `(Type,Country)` group? Could we ever get a more complicated scheme like Mobile 4366, which might cause 43650 to be omitted?

Comment: 4366 would not cause 43650 to be dropped, because 43650 does not start with 4366.
4365 would cause 43650 to be dropped.

Comment: That's my point: the solutions here *would* cause 43650 to be dropped in favor of 4366, simply because they look at length, not whether the lead digits of prefixB are contained elsewhere in the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably *Prefix* column in your DataFrame is of *int* type,
so the first thing is to convert it to *String*:

```
df.Prefix = df.Prefix.astype(str)
```

Then define 2 functions:

1. A function to check whether for the current row exists any
   other row with shorter *Prefix*, which is also a "starting part"
   of "my" *Prefix*:

   ```
   def hasShorter(row, grp):
       myPref = row.Prefix
       ind = row.name
       prefsToCompare = grp.drop(ind).Prefix
       # Leave only shorter Prefixes
       prefsToCompare = prefsToCompare[prefsToCompare.str.len() < len(myPref)]
       if prefsToCompare.size == 0:
           return False  # No rows with shorter prefix
       # Is any other Prefix less specific?
       return prefsToCompare.apply(lambda x: myPref.startswith(x)).any()
   ```
2. A function to apply to each group - a filter, eliminating rows
   that don't have any shorter "neighbour Prefix" (starting with the same
   characters):

   ```
   def groupFilter(grp):
       return grp[~grp.apply(hasShorter, axis=1, grp=grp)]
   ```

Then, to get your expected result, run:

```
result = df.groupby(['Type', 'Country'], as_index=False,
    group_keys=False).apply(groupFilter)
```

The result, for your data sample, is:

```
  Prefix     Type  Country
0     43  Fixline  Austria
2  43650   Mobile  Austria
4  43676   Mobile  Austria
```

If you need, convert *Prefix* column back to *int*.
Or maybe this column initially was and should remain of *str* type
(your Prefixes are just codes, accidentally composed of only digits,
but the should be treated as **strings**)?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be the smartest to slice the `Prefix` first to the wantened and know length and then drop the duplicates.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Prefix':[43, 431, 43650, 436501, 43676], 
                   'Type':['Fixline', 'Fixline', 'Mobile', 'Mobile', 'Mobile'], 
                   'Country':['Austria']*5})

df['Prefix'] = df[['Prefix', 'Type']].apply(lambda x: str(x[0])[:2] if x[1]=='Fixline' else str(x[0])[:5], axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df
>>>
  Prefix     Type  Country
0     43  Fixline  Austria
2  43650   Mobile  Austria
4  43676   Mobile  Austria
```